# OpenCV and connecting a webcam?

Tags: opencv, webcam

I'm struggling with connecting my webcam in [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV). My laptop's webcam in Windows 7 64-bit works properly. But if I connect another webcam, the code doesn't work at all:

```
capWebcam = cvCaptureFromCAM(0); 
if(capWebcam == NULL) { 
    printf("error: capture is NULL \n"); 
    getchar(); 
    return(-1);
}
```

Since there isn't any webcam, it returns the message error. I disabled laptop webcam, and it worked, but I'm getting black screen.

I tried two webcams, namely [Logitech HD Pro C920](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-pro-webcam-c920) and [LifeCam Cinema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LifeCam#Cinema) from Microsoft. This is the line responsible to get the cam:

```
CvCapture* mycapWebcam = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
```

I changed the 0 to another value (0-10) and this is information about this structure:

> CvCapture* cvCaptureFromCAM(int index)
>
> Initializes capturing a video from a camera.
>
> Parameter:    index – Index of the camera to be used. If there is only one camera or it does not matter what camera is used -1 may be passed.
>
> The function cvCaptureFromCAM() allocates and initializes the CvCapture structure for reading a video stream from the camera. Currently two camera interfaces can be used on Windows: Video for Windows (VFW) and Matrox Imaging Library (MIL); and two on Linux: V4L and FireWire (IEEE1394).
>
> To release the structure, use ReleaseCapture.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: are you sure that the webcam is open normally  ? i mean , you need to disable your laptop webcam , did you?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, I'm sure that the webcam works properly, what do you mean by saying disable laptop webcam and how I do so?

Comment: if you use windows , you will find the USB camera for laptop in "device manager" in "imaging devices"  then right click and disable it, i faced this problem before and it worked with me

Comment: Thank you again so much. The webcam works but I'm getting black screen. Do you know why?

Comment: i think that you don't show the image , are you? , and you're welcome anytime :)

Comment: try this link :http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CameraCapture

Comment: I did actually. The code works with my laptop webcam but not with an external webcam. I'm using LifeCam webcam. I did search about this bug, I found a bench of guys facing same problem.

Comment: actually i don't know , i hope you can fix your problem

Comment: I solved the problem. I did follow another tutorial to set up my OpenCV, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a different API - look at [my answer to Stack Overflow question *OpenCV on Mac is not opening USB web camera*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14188280/1598485).

The first frame quite often is black (I don't know why). Try to wait some time and get another frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using another camera you should set 1 as index:

```
capWebcam = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
```