# OpenCV on Mac is not opening USB web camera

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, webcam

I have been unsuccessful using [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)'s VideoCapture.open(int) to get video capture from a USB web cam in my [MacBook Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) running Mac OS X v10.7 (Lion). Using open(0) successfully gets capture from the iSight camera. But I didn't have any luck trying to find the WebCam.

The WebCam is installed and works well with [Skype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype), and the [macam](http://webcam-osx.sourceforge.net/) driver application.

Here is a portion of the code that I'm using:

```
VideoCapture cap; 
for (int i = 1; i < 1500; i++) {
    if (cap.open(i))
    {
        cout << "Found camera %d\n" << i;
        break;
    }
}
if(!cap.isOpened()) {  // Check if we succeeded
    return -1;
}
```

If I initialize `i` with 0 it immediately finds the iSight camera. If I initialize `i` with 1, then it finds iSight again when `i` = 500.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run your code without this line: `break;`. Probably you will find more than just one camera, and one of them will WebCam.
Note that parameter of `cap.open` is not only the number of camera - it also defines which API you want to use:

Camera dispatching method: `index` is the camera number.

- If given an index from 0 to 99, it tries to find the first
- API that can access a given camera index.
- Add multiples of 100 to select an API (comment from cap.cpp)

Possibilities (taken from highgui_c.h):

```
CV_CAP_ANY      =0,     // autodetect  
CV_CAP_MIL      =100,   // MIL proprietary drivers  
CV_CAP_VFW      =200,   // platform native  
CV_CAP_V4L      =200,
CV_CAP_V4L2     =200,  
CV_CAP_FIREWARE =300,   // IEEE 1394 drivers  
CV_CAP_FIREWIRE =300,  
CV_CAP_IEEE1394 =300,  
CV_CAP_DC1394   =300,  
CV_CAP_CMU1394  =300,  
CV_CAP_STEREO   =400,   // TYZX proprietary drivers  
CV_CAP_TYZX     =400,  
CV_TYZX_LEFT    =400,  
CV_TYZX_RIGHT   =401,  
CV_TYZX_COLOR   =402,  
CV_TYZX_Z       =403,  
CV_CAP_QT       =500,   // QuickTime  
CV_CAP_UNICAP   =600,   // Unicap drivers  
CV_CAP_DSHOW    =700,   // DirectShow (via videoInput)  
CV_CAP_PVAPI    =800,   // PvAPI, Prosilica GigE SDK  
CV_CAP_OPENNI   =900,   // OpenNI (for Kinect)  
CV_CAP_OPENNI_ASUS =910,   // OpenNI (for Asus Xtion)  
CV_CAP_ANDROID  =1000,  // Android  
CV_CAP_XIAPI    =1100,   // XIMEA Camera API  
CV_CAP_AVFOUNDATION = 1200  // AVFoundation framework for iOS (OS X Lion will have the same API)
```

Probably `CV_CAP_AVFOUNDATION = 1200` is what you are looking for - try to start you loop from 1200 and don't forget to remove `break;` and I think that you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I used the code below and it only found the iSight camera with API=0 (any) and API=500 (QuickTime). Any other ideas?  `int findCamera() {
    
    for (int api =0; api <= 1200; api+=100) {
        for (int cam = 0; cam <= 99; cam++) {
            VideoCapture cap(api+cam);
            if (cap.open(api+cam))
            {
                cout << "Found camera at api " << api << " camera " << cam << endl;
            }
            
        }
    }
    return 0;
    
    
}`  (sorry for the poor formatting)

Comment: 1. Use the latest version of OpenCV.
2. Try to build OpenCV with some other library(libraries) from the list - the best option is to check with of them is used by one program which is working fine with your camera and use this one.

Comment: this helped me get my logitech c922 working, needed: `capture.open(CV_CAP_DSHOW);`