# How can pass 2 FPS for RTSP camera using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, object-detection, rtsp, frame-rate

I am getting **180000.0 FPS** using **rtscap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)**. and while running its give me 1**5 to 18 FPS**. But I want **2(FPS)** frame per second.

[image]

Please Anyone can help me? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Not sure you can change the frame rate this easily with opencv. 
You might be better off just skipping all frames except 2 each second. 
[As this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068277/change-frame-rate-in-opencv-3-4-2)

Comment: When i am skipping frames its uses all CPU cores in Nvidia GPU instead of GPU. That's why its hitting.

Comment: i want frame as per whatever number i passed for frame.

Comment: You have to decode all the frames anyway, because some are predictive frames. 
If the issue is where the decoding is happening, cpu vs gpu. 
It might be that opencv is using an ffmpeg backend which isn't supporting h/w acceleration. 
You could try configure the back end to use gstreamer with nvidia plugins for decoding maybe.