# Can't grab frame from webcamera

Tags: opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.4.6, VS2010 with Windows 7 64 bit. I could not grab frame from the camera. The code below is working fine for avi file, but not working to capture from camera. Can anyone help me, how can I capture the frame? Thanks in advance.......

Actually problem in this portion:

bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

```
    if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
    {
        cout << "Cannot read a frame from video file" << endl;
        break;
    }
```

**The full source code:**

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0

    if(!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
    double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

    cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

    while(1)
    {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
            cout << "Cannot read a frame from video file" << endl;
            break;
        }

        imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

        if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `VideoCapture cap(-1);`

Comment: Check the following post, it answers this problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386891/opencv-cant-capture-the-frame-from-the-webcam/27084623#27084623

Answer (score 1):

## **You should read the first frame before using while loop like this:**

```
Mat frame;
cap.read(frame); 
while(1)
{
    bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

    if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
    {
        cout << "Cannot read a frame from video file" << endl;
        break;
    }

    imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

    if(waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
    {
        cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
        break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeyuel, could you please explain this? I have same problem as Dejan, but in my case reading first two frames fails. Mat frame;
cap.read(frame);cap.read(frame); solves the problem, but looks ugly..