# Java webcamera crash when detecting first frame

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, opencv

Actually i am using opencv 3.0.0 when detecting first frame camera become crash in Eclipse. 
Code look like this

```
public class main
{
static {
    System.out.println("java.library.path="+System.getProperty("java.library.path"));

    System.load(new File("/Desktop/opencv-3.0.0/build22/lib/libopencv_java300.dylib").getAbsolutePath());
//  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    System.load(new File("/Documents/Mourish/java-proj/FaceDetector/libFaceDetector.so").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("Library loaded");

}

public static void main(String argv[]) {
    int n = 0 ;
    final Scalar    FACE_RECT_COLOR     = new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255);

    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
//  CascadeClassifier cascadename = new CascadeClassifier("/Documents/FD/sample/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");

     String s = "/Documents/FD/sample/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml";

     Imshow im = new Imshow("window");
    VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);

    if(!camera.isOpened()){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    else {
        Mat frame = new Mat();
        Mat out = new Mat();
        while(true){
            if (camera.read(frame)){

//              
                n = FaceDetector.sample(frame, out, faces, s);
                System.out.println("Frame Obtained");
                System.out.println("Captured Frame Width " + 
                frame.width() + " Height " + frame.height());


                Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++)
                  Imgproc.rectangle(frame, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);
                im.showImage(frame);
                Imgcodecs.imwrite("/Documents/FD/sample/camera.jpg", frame);

                System.out.println("OK");

                break;
            }
        }   
    }
//  return n;
}
}
```

show some exception in im.showImage(). i import external jars opencv_300.jar. Exception look like this..,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/highgui/Highgui
    at com.atul.JavaOpenCV.Imshow.showImage(Imshow.java:77)
    at main.main(main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opencv.highgui.Highgui
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.secu`enter code here`rity.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
Pls help me to find actual issue....
```

Comment: What operating system are you on? Any logfile? Does the camera work reliably with other applications? what bus is the camera on? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916434/cant-grab-frame-from-webcamera and try -1 as videosource

Comment: Iam using Mac os x 10.9.5. Actually camera detecting first frame, detceting frame  i was write into the directory. Frame shows detecting rectangle for face

Comment: @x29a Thank you for you reply, now i tried same thing you referred in stack but same issue happen