# Error R6010, when i want to use my webcamera. Why is it called?

Tags: c++, opencv

I use VS 2010, with opencv. Whatever i try when i want to use my wecamera (on my laptop), i get this: "r6010 abort() has been called".
And a gray window shows up.
Here is the code:

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;


int main()
{

    Mat image;

    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    namedWindow("Window", 1);

    while (1)
    {
        cap >> image;
        imshow("Windwow",image);
        waitKey(33);
    }

}
```

Btw, in another program, what i got from youtube, it says "Error: Frame is NULL".

Comment: `"Windwow"` != `"Window"`

Comment: I corrected it, but the error is still there :/

Comment: The [documentation for VideoCapture::read](http://tinyurl.com/nhpwnf3) says you may need to copy the image before you can do anything with it.

Comment: See this question, similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386891/opencv-cant-capture-the-frame-from-the-webcam.

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop, I have to use device 1 to access the webcam. You should also check whether `cap` is opened, e.g.

```
cap.open(1);
if(!cap.isOpened())
    return -1;
```

Comment: Cap is opened, the problem isn't that.

Comment: Which line is actually causing it to crash? Does image get its data set when you read from cap?

Comment: this line: imshow("Windwow",image);
If i balk that line, it works. Exactly the program useless then, but i dont get any error.

Comment: I would think that image.data is null then. How did you check that "Cap is opened"?  I suggest `bool VideoCapture::read(Mat& image)` instead of  `>>` so you can check the status easily.

Comment: BTW, what version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: I checked it on this way like you said to do it: 
cap.open(0);
if(!cap.isOpened())
    return -1;
And I use OpenCV 2.4.9 version