# OpenCV-Driver for firewire camera

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to use a firewire, sony handycam with an OpenCV application. I believe I need to download another driver but CMU 1394 driver that integrates firewire cameras seems to be only compatible with windows. Is there soemthign I can use for a mac to make my camera open with

```
   CvCapture*capture=0;
    capture=cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
```

Comment: Are you able to use the camera with any other program? Try with any; if you were using GNU/Linux I'd suggest Coriander. If you can't, then there is some problem with the driver. I don't know if this holds for Mac, but in GNU/Linux, a typical problem is that you need to add permissions to /dev/raw1394 and /dev/ieee1394.

Comment: Yes I've tried it with an Openframeworks application, just can't seem to get it to work with OpenCV

Comment: I don't think it will help, but you may try to use different API - see ma answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187866/opencv-on-mac-not-opening-usb-web-camera/14188280#14188280

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Changing permissions to /dev/raw1394 and /dev/ieee1394 worked for me (testing a Prosilica EC with Ubuntu Lucid).

Comment: I am having same issue on Mac, can you tell me how to change these permissions please? Thanks